# R Shiny: selectInput inside splitLayout

Tags: r, shiny

When the `selectInput` widget is inside `splitLayout` with `multiple` mode on, there is something wrong. The dropdown selection area disappears when the width is small.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  splitLayout(selectInput("x","x",choices = LETTERS,selected = LETTERS,multiple = TRUE),
              br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br())
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any advice. Thanks.

Comment: why do you need splitlayout?

Comment: because `fluidrow` is not flexible enough in setting widths. How do you evenly place 9 widgets side by side in a row.

Comment: looks like a bug.